# Button Click to Send User to Start of Program

Tags: java, button, random, javafx, restart

I have an equations program that I'm working on, which randomly selects one of 50 equations, then takes the user through a series of scenes in order to solve it. Once the user solves the equation, they're asked if they want another equation. If they answer no, the program closes. If they answer yes, the program is supposed to randomly select another equation, then take them through the scenes to solve that one.

The program works just as I want it to the first time through. However, if the user selects "yes" for another equation, the program displays the END of the first scene, showing them the previous problem that they've already solved.

How can I send the user to the beginning of the scene, so that a new equation is randomly selected?

Here’s the relevant code for Scene 1:

```
package Equations;

import java.util.Random;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;

public class equationsapp extends Application
    implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

@Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

stage = primaryStage;

Random eqrdmzr = new Random();
int randomNumber = eqrdmzr.nextInt(3) + 1;

if (randomNumber == 1) {
isolCounterCoeff = 2;
isolVrblb = new Label("+");
isolCounter1a = 7;
isolCounter2a = 17;
slvCoeff = 2;
slvEqVrblTerm = new Text("2n");
slvEqWhlNmbrInt = 10;
slvEqWhlNmbr = new Text("10");
}

if(randomNumber == 2) {
isolCounterCoeff = 2;
isolVrblb = new Label("+");
isolVrblb.setVisible(false);
isolCounter1a = -18;
isolCounter2a = 4;
slvCoeff = 2;
slvEqVrblTerm = new Text("2n");
slvEqWhlNmbrInt = 22;
slvEqWhlNmbr = new Text("22");
}

if(randomNumber == 3) {
isolCounterCoeff = 3;
isolVrblb = new Label("+");
isolVrblb.setVisible(false);
isolCounter1a = -5;
isolCounter2a = 19;
slvCoeff = 3;
slvEqVrblTerm = new Text("3n");
slvEqWhlNmbrInt = 24;
slvEqWhlNmbr = new Text("24");
}

//Build Scene 1 - Top BorderPane
Text isolText = new Text("Isolate the Variable Term");
isolText.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 16pt");

//Build Scene 1 - Center BorderPane
Label isolCoeff = new Label();
isolCoeff.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 24pt;");
isolCoeff.setText(Integer.toString(isolCounterCoeff));

Label isolVrbl = new Label("n");
isolVrbl.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 24pt;");

isolVrblb.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 24pt;");
isolVrblb.managedProperty().bind(isolVrblb.visibleProperty());

Label isolEqIntLeft = new Label();
isolEqIntLeft.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 24pt;");
isolEqIntLeft.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0));
isolEqIntLeft.setText(Integer.toString(isolCounter1a));
isolEqIntLeft.managedProperty().bind(isolEqIntLeft.visibleProperty());

Label isolEqualSign = new Label("=");
isolEqualSign.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 24pt;");

Label isolEqIntRight = new Label();
isolEqIntRight.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 24pt;");
isolEqIntRight.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 10));
isolEqIntRight.setText(Integer.toString(isolCounter2a));

//Build Scene 1 - Bottom BorderPane
Label isolLbl1 = new Label();
isolLbl1.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 22pt;");

isolEqIntLeft.setText(Integer.toString(isolCounter1a));
isolLbl1.setText(Integer.toString(isolCounter1b));

//Create GridPanes and Fill Them
GridPane isolGridPane1 = new GridPane();
isolGridPane1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
isolGridPane1.add(isolText, 0, 0);

GridPane isolGridPane2 = new GridPane();
isolGridPane2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
isolGridPane2.add(isolCoeff, 0, 0);
isolGridPane2.add(isolVrbl, 1, 0);
isolGridPane2.add(isolVrblb, 2, 0);
isolGridPane2.add(isolEqIntLeft, 3, 0);
isolGridPane2.add(isolEqualSign, 4, 0);
isolGridPane2.add(isolEqIntRight, 5, 0);

GridPane isolGridPane3 = new GridPane();
isolGridPane3.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
isolGridPane3.setHgap(25.0);
isolGridPane3.setVgap(10.0);
isolGridPane3.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 20, 0));
isolGridPane3.add(isolbtn1, 0, 0); 
isolGridPane3.add(isolLbl1, 1, 0);
isolGridPane3.add(isolBtn2, 2, 0);
isolGridPane3.add(isolBtn3, 4, 0);
isolGridPane3.add(isolLbl2, 5, 0);
isolGridPane3.add(isolBtn4, 6, 0);
isolGridPane3.add(isolContinueBtn, 3, 1);

//Add GridPane to BorderPane
BorderPane isolBorderPane = new BorderPane();
isolBorderPane.setTop(isolGridPane1);
isolBorderPane.setCenter(isolGridPane2);
isolBorderPane.setBottom(isolGridPane3);

//Add BorderPane to Scene
scene1 = new Scene(isolBorderPane, 500, 300);

//Add the scene to the stage, set the title and show the stage
primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
primaryStage.setTitle("Equations");
primaryStage.show();
```

Here’s the event handler that’s supposed to send them back to the start of Stage 1:

```
Button yesBtn = new Button("Yes");
yesBtn.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 12pt;");
yesBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
public void handle (ActionEvent event) {
if (event.getSource() == yesBtn) {
stage.setScene(scene1);
}
}
});
```

Comment: i just wanted to clear some doubts that, your target is to change the equation question based on the selection, so if this is the case why you are changing the scene, instead of that have one scene for whole process and change the contents in it.

Comment: @Hareesh - to be honest, I'm doing what I've seen on the Internet in other examples. I had a suspicion that this was my problem, but everything else I've tried (such as a do...while loop, and trying to send it to the beginning of the method) hasn't worked. 

"have one scene for whole process and change the contents in it."
Can you give me an example of what you mean?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Just setting the scene on the stage doesn't **reload** the contents of the scene..*

**How to resolve this.. ?**

As far as I see, you do not need to change scene. Create a simple method called `loadMainDisplay()`, which creates the `BorderPane isolBorderPane` by the adding the grid to it with all the required controls.

```
BorderPane loadMainDisplay() {
    ...
}
```

You can call it initially while loading the contents. Later, when the user selects `YES` for another equation, call this method, again.

```
yesBtn.setOnAction(event -> {
    if (event.getSource() == yesBtn) {
          scene.setRoot(loadMainDisplay());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry, but I'm not quite following you:

Am I putting the `loadMainDisplay() ` method in place of `BorderPane isolBorderPane`, or am I adding it somewhere in the code (if so, where?).

Also, am I adding it once, or twice (once for initial run-through, and again for the YES option)?

Finally, can you show me what the method would look like. Am I adding `isolBorderPane` only, or am I adding the `isolGridPanes` as well? (I'm sorry, but I'm still new to programming, and am not as intuitive as someone who's been doing this for a while)?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class ChangePaneExample extends Application{

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main( String[] args ){
    launch( args );
}

int screenNumber = 1;
private GridPane root;
private Scene rootScene;
private StackPane changingPane;

/**
 * @see javafx.application.Application#start(javafx.stage.Stage)
 * @param primaryStage
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Override
public void start( Stage primaryStage ) throws Exception{
    root = new GridPane();
    rootScene = new Scene( root );
    primaryStage.setScene( rootScene );

    changingPane = new StackPane();

    changeScreen();

    Button changeBtn = new Button();
    changeBtn.setText( "Change Screen" );

    changeBtn.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle( ActionEvent arg0 ){
            changeScreen();
        }
    } );

    root.addRow( 1, changeBtn );
    root.addRow( 2, changingPane );

    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 */
private void changeScreen(){
    if( screenNumber > 2 ) screenNumber = 1;
    changingPane.getChildren().clear();
    changingPane.getChildren().add( getDisplayPane( screenNumber + "" ) );
    screenNumber++;
}

public static Pane getDisplayPane( String uniqueIdOfScreen ){

    switch( uniqueIdOfScreen ){
        case "1":
            return getIsoletedGridPane2();
        case "2":
            return getIsoletedGridPane1();
        default:
            break;
    }
    return null;
}

public static Pane getIsoletedGridPane2(){

    GridPane isolGridPane3 = new GridPane();

    Label label = new Label();
    label.setText( "this is isolated GridPane--------------- 2 ----------------------" );

    isolGridPane3.getChildren().add( label );

    return isolGridPane3;
}

public static Pane getIsoletedGridPane1(){

    HBox isolGridPane3 = new HBox();

    Label label = new Label();
    label.setText( "this is isolated HBox --------------------------- 1 ----------------------------" );

    isolGridPane3.getChildren().add( label );

    return isolGridPane3;
}

 }
```

This is one example of changing the Panes on the scene.
Changing the entire scene is not recommended way.